# Qt C++ table fill empty items

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have a simple `tableWidget` in my GUI that displays 2 columns. In this table I want to fill data which will be saved to a txt-file later. This works well. 
My problem now is, that if the user doesn`t fill all cells, my program crashes.

I can find a cell containing nothing by using

```
ui->tab_NFF->item(i,0)->text().isEmpty()
   qDebug() << "Item " <<i<<",0 is empty" ;
```

but when I try to fill that cell with some text it doesnt work. I tried this:

```
if (ui->tab_NFF->item(i,0)->text().isEmpty())
    ui->tab_NFF->item(i,0)->setText("0");
```

Does this item exist after all? Is it just empty or does the computer try to fill a value in a non-existing "item" ? If so, how do I create a new item?

Comment: Can you provide code where you fill table and how you save data in text file?

Comment: "it doesnt work" is not a very useful error description, and neither is "my program crashes"... Try providing exact error messages, stack trace, etc. Like here I could guess you have segmentation fault because of a null pointer, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't create an item, there isn't one. Just an empty table with a limited number of rows and columns (that you can choose).

You have to create the item using:

```
QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
```

I invite you to read the [documentation about `QTableWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#details) for more details.

Comment: And `ui->tab_NFF->item(i,0)` should be compared to `NULL`. Otherwise really empty cells can crash the program.